# How to convert string to HTML? Elixir Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a function in View

```
 def show_tree() do
    tree = "<ul>"
    tree = tree <> "<li><a href='edir/1'>1 item <a/></li> <li><a href='edir/1'>2 item<a/></li> </ul>"
    tree
  end
```

If call it in temlpate index.html.eex via *<%= show_tree %>* then I get

```
<ul><li><a href='edir/1'>1 item <a/></li> <li><a href='edir/1'>2 item<a/></li> </ul>
```

But I need HTML list with HTML links.

```
1 item
2 item
```

How I can do it?

Comment: Use the `raw` function: `raw(tree)`.

Comment: You mean an ordered list? If so then do `<ol>` instead of `<ul>`.

Comment: _Sidenote:_ this is extremely bad code, making use of the worst anti-pattern. `raw` _always_ should be used as a last resort.

Comment: I edited question. Not only list, all HTML tags.